# Accessing pandas index level values in some way that isn't terribly verbose and also works when the variables aren't indexes?

Tags: pandas, indexing

Here is a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a = [1,1,2], b = [4,5,4], x = [7,8,9]))
```

If I want the min of `b`, I just do this:

```
df.b.min()
```

It's 10 characters.

Now say I need to use indexing.  In my case, it's because I need to integrate `xarray` into my project.

```
df = df.set_index(['a', 'b'])
```

If I want the min of `b`, now I have to type:

```
df.index.get_level_values('b').min()
```

Problems:

1. This is 36 characters!  260% more in this example!
2. This breaks all of my old code that used the previous, briefer formulation.

Is there something that can access a variable *irrespective* of whether it's an index, and that doesn't take up half of the page width?

Apologies if this is something of a rant, but this is why I've avoided using pandas indexing until now.  I'd love there to be some simple solution.  Is there one?

Comment: reset_index.....

Comment: @BENY if there isn't a better way, there should be.

Comment: You can pass `drop=False` to `set_index` so the columns to be used as index aren't dropped, allowing you to use `df.b.min()` still. Assuming that: 1. you will not process the index after setting it, or at least you don't necessarily want those changes to be reflected in the original columns. 2. you don't mind having those "extra columns" in the DataFrame. Then this is probably the best you can get.

Comment: Isn´t the main motivation of `xarray` precisely to make it easy to work with labeled N-dimensional data, namely to provide a cleaner alternative to using `pandas.MultiIndex` ? `pandas` is designed to work with tabular data.  Working with `pandas.MultiIndex` is essentially adding extra dimensions to the data in a flattened way, which is outside the main scope of `pandas`, making it complicated to work with. That is the way I see it...  the reason why working with multi-indices in `pandas` is not that straightforward and why the `pandas.MultiIndex` API is not great